# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el archivo de texto a un array c++?

Tags: c++, array, fstream

hice un código que lee archivos txt y los imprime por consola pero quiero que los datos del texto se guarden en un array para luego hacer el manejo en cadenas y compararlos con otras cadenas, intente hacer una solución pero no logre obtenerla, si alguien me podría ayudar se lo agradecería, les dejo parte de mi código  muchas gracias

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void leer();
int main() {
    leer();
    return 0;
}
void leer() {
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;
    archivo.open("programacion.txt", ios::in);
    if (archivo.fail()) {
        cout << "no se encontro el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!archivo.eof()) {
        getline(archivo, texto);
        cout << texto << endl;

    }
    archivo.close();

}
```

Comment: Simplemente copia el contenido en un array.

Comment: pero como.....?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener directamente el buffer del archivo mediante [**rdbuf()**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/rdbuf).
De esta manera:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

...

std::ifstream file("text.txt");
std::string buf;

if(file.is_open()) {
   // Guardando el contenido del archivo para luego pasarlo a un std::string
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << file.rdbuf();
   buf = ss.str();
}

// Hacer algo con buf
```

Answer (score -1):

Tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Saber cuántas líneas hay en tu fichero
2. Te creas un array de n elementos(siendo n el número de lineas)
3. Y vas almacenando en cada posición del array todo lo que contenga cada línea

En mi opinión esto es algo que no se usa, es un poco inútil guardar lo que ponga un fichero de texto en un array, ya que normalmente se hace al revés(lees un dato en un string o int y lo guardas en un fichero).